# Tableau to MongoDB Connection

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api

I am trying to evaluate Mongodb and tableau integration.

I am facing an issue. I have installed Mongodb enterprise along with Mongodb BI connector on my windows machine.
And created sample test document. The tableau connection is successful, able to see the databases on tableau desktop, but unable to see tables (documents).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with MySQL ODBC connector, I was using the latest version of MySQL ODBC. I have degraded the ODBC connector then the issue got resolved.